# Error in MLE estimation of degrees of freedom of chi-squared distribution

Tags: r, chi-squared, estimation, mle, log-likelihood

I have been tasked with estimating the degrees of freedom *k* of the probability distribution function of several chi-squared distributions using maximum likelihood estimation.
So I started by drawing 20 random values from the chi-distribution and proceeded to use maximum likelihood to estimate the degrees of freedom *k* in R.

The likelihood function of the chi-distribution is assumed to be:

[image: Picture of log-likelihood function]

```
library('maxLik')
library('lmtest')



 > n <- 20
 > df = 3
 > df <- 3
 > chi20 <- rchisq(n, df)
 > X <- chi20


loglikfun <- function(param) {
    if (param[1] <= 0) return(NA)
    #return(sum(dchisq(X = chi20, df = param[1], log = TRUE])))
    return((param[1]/2-1)*(sum(log(X)))-(1/2*sum(X)-n*log(gamma(param[1]/2)))-(n*param[1]/2*log(2)))
}

mle <- maxLik(Loglikfun, start = c(df = 1))

summary(mle)
```

However, rather than getting an estimate of approximately 3, I get 7496171 with a bunch of NaNs errors.

[image: Output of above code]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have just transcribed the formula incorrectly. The section that you have written as

```r
-(1/2*sum(X)-n*log(gamma(param[1]/2)))
```

Should not have the outer parentheses, since these have the effect of negating the sign of the `-n*log(gamma(param[1]/2))` term. It therefore gets *added* to the result, when it should be *subtracted* according to the formula.

A more general observation here is that it's easier to keep track when implementing a mathematical formula if you match the names consistently and use spaces around the operators to make your code more readable. This might seem like a minor point, but in reality it is a frequent source of easily-avoided bugs.

Another point is that the function can be made more efficient by allowing R's native vectorization to try several parameter estimates at once. Effectively you can get this "for free" by removing any zero and negative values in the input vector first.

One way to correct the implementation would be:

```r
loglikfun <- function(k) 
{
  k[k <= 0] <- NA
  
  (k / 2 - 1) * sum(log(X)) - sum(X) / 2 - n * log(gamma(k / 2)) - n * k * log(2) / 2
}
```

We can check that this gives sensible results by plotting its output:

```r
set.seed(100)

df <- 3
n  <- 20
X  <- rchisq(n, df)

parameter_estimate <- seq(0, 10, 0.1)
log_likelihood <- loglikfun(parameter_estimate)
plot(parameter_estimate, log_likelihood, type = "l")
abline(v = parameter_estimate[which.max(log_likelihood)], lty = 2, col = 2)
abline(h = max(log_likelihood, na.rm = TRUE), lty = 2, col = 2)
```

[image]

Where we can see the maximum log likelihood occurs at around 3, which is expected from the input.

If we try your `maxLik` code now, we can see we get the correct answer:

```r
mle <- maxLik(loglikfun, start = c(k = 1))

summary(mle)
#> --------------------------------------------
#> Maximum Likelihood estimation
#> Newton-Raphson maximisation, 5 iterations
#> Return code 8: successive function values within relative tolerance limit (reltol)
#> Log-Likelihood: -35.58475 
#> 1  free parameters
#> Estimates:
#>   Estimate Std. error t value  Pr(> t)    
#> k   2.8960     0.4523   6.403 1.52e-10 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
#> --------------------------------------------
```

and

```r
df <- 5
n <- 100
X  <- rchisq(n, df)

mle <- maxLik(loglikfun, start = c(k = 1))

summary(mle)
#> --------------------------------------------
#> Maximum Likelihood estimation
#> Newton-Raphson maximisation, 6 iterations
#> Return code 8: successive function values within relative tolerance limit (reltol)
#> Log-Likelihood: -243.5511 
#> 1  free parameters
#> Estimates:
#>   Estimate Std. error t value Pr(> t)    
#> k   4.9735     0.2851   17.45  <2e-16 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
#> --------------------------------------------
```

Where we see that the parameter estimates are now close to the parameters used in the creation of the random sample.

<sup>Created on 2021-11-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

F(k)= -n*log(2*gamma(k/2)+(k/2-1)*SumIFom1toN(log(Xi/2))-
-SumIFom1toN(Xi)/2

You can optimize
QS=SumIFom1toN(log(Xi/2);
HS=SumIFom1toN(Xi)/2;

F(k,QS,HS)= -n*log(2*gamma(k/2)+(k/2-1)*QS-HS;
Calculation precission for machine means was out of consideration;